# how to make search functionality based on dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I m facing problem in below code, when I'm selecting a position in dropdown menu filter option is one is not  working.

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("zui-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

Code snippet

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("zui-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

function myFunction1() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput1");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("zui-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput2");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("zui-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.zui-table {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.zui-table thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

#zui-table tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 18%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput1 {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 18%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput2 {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 18%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<select id="myInput1" onkeyup="myFunction1()" placeholder="Search for psition..">
  <option value="volvo">Select postion</option>
  <option value="volvo">C</option>
  <option value="saab">PG</option>
  <option value="fiat">SG</option>
  <option value="audi">PF</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myInput2" onkeyup="myFunction2()" placeholder="Search for Height.." title="Type in a name">



<table id="zui-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Height</th>
      <th>Born</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TeMarcus Cousins</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>6'11"</td>
      <td>08-13-1990</td>
      <td>$4,917,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Isaiah Thomas</td>
      <td>PG</td>
      <td>5'9"</td>
      <td>02-07-1989</td>
      <td>$473,604</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ben McLemore</td>
      <td>SG</td>
      <td>6'5"</td>
      <td>02-11-1993</td>
      <td>$2,895,960</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Marcus Thornton</td>
      <td>SG</td>
      <td>6'4"</td>
      <td>05-05-1987</td>
      <td>$7,000,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jason Thompson</td>
      <td>PF</td>
      <td>6'11"</td>
      <td>06-21-1986</td>
      <td>$3,001,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if any one help me out why drop down functionality not working/ its very thankful

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 thing you'll need to change in your code on select menu,

1. Change the values of `option`.
2. Change the event of `select` from `onkeyup` to `onchange`, `onkeyup` won't work when you'll select an option with cursor.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("zui-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

function myFunction1() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput1");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("zui-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput2");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("zui-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.zui-table {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.zui-table thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

#zui-table tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 18%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput1 {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 18%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput2 {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 18%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<select id="myInput1" onchange="myFunction1()" placeholder="Search for psition..">
  <option value="0">Select postion</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="PG">PG</option>
  <option value="SG">SG</option>
  <option value="PF">PF</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myInput2" onkeyup="myFunction2()" placeholder="Search for Height.." title="Type in a name">



<table id="zui-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Height</th>
      <th>Born</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TeMarcus Cousins</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>6'11"</td>
      <td>08-13-1990</td>
      <td>$4,917,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Isaiah Thomas</td>
      <td>PG</td>
      <td>5'9"</td>
      <td>02-07-1989</td>
      <td>$473,604</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ben McLemore</td>
      <td>SG</td>
      <td>6'5"</td>
      <td>02-11-1993</td>
      <td>$2,895,960</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Marcus Thornton</td>
      <td>SG</td>
      <td>6'4"</td>
      <td>05-05-1987</td>
      <td>$7,000,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jason Thompson</td>
      <td>PF</td>
      <td>6'11"</td>
      <td>06-21-1986</td>
      <td>$3,001,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<select id="myInput1" onchange="myFunction1()" placeholder="Search for psition..">
  <option value="0">Select postion</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="PG">PG</option>
  <option value="SG">SG</option>
  <option value="PF">PF</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have use, instead of using **onkeyup** use **onchange** , and also change **values** of **option** then it's work fine, like this :

```
<select  id="myInput1" onchange="myFunction1()" placeholder="Search for psition.." >
  <option value="volvo">Select postion</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="PG">PG</option>
    <option value="SG">SG</option>
    <option value="PF">PF</option>
  </select>
```

[modified code](https://jsfiddle.net/1sp2Lgro/1/)